# itextsharp XML worker slow performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am using the iTExtsharp5.X version for comverting html to pdf. I am facing performance issues with it when printing a pdf which has just around 20 pages. It takes around 30 to 40 seconds. The html I use is pretty stylized and I need to retain the format. Is this the expected performance for iTextSharp? I have tried different things based on my research on this but cant seem to see any change in performance. I am getting an acceptable performance for 3 or 4 pages but 20 pages seems to be taking forever!!

Comment: Performance can be bad if your HTML is bad. For instance: some people use tables that are deeply nested: tables in tables in tables in tables result in bad performance. That shouldn't surprise anyone.

Comment: The HTML is actuallly XHTML (result are taken from ckeditor) and i am using htmlagiliypack to validate it. I dont get any parser errors. But yes, these are quite stylized and need to look  professional.

Comment: Is it possible to share the HTML?

Comment: I would have loved to but there is too much confidential info in there. So I cant do that. I am happy with the output that it generates but concerned with the performance. I also rechecked the html and I see there are no nested tables as well. The file is quite huge though. I am trying to print around 10 tables (not nested) into a single pdf. The output would be 20to 23 pages. I need to know if this is the standard performance. Thanks

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I use a web app to run this. An ASP.Net MVC app so you can imagine the problems associated with such long running tasks.

Comment: Each table row would have lots of css and few images to be loaded using the image url that is in the html string that is passed on from the html editor.

Comment: It's really, *really* hard to answer the question without the HTML at hand. Not even if you "sanitize" it? Remove confidential data or replace it with dummy data?

Comment: Please also share your code of calling the xml worker.